# fopen can't read arabic characters

Tags: ms-word, fopen, arabic

This function reads (document.doc) files.. But it turns arabic characters into english characters

I want to make it read arabic characters , Or remove it at least.

```
    function word($filename){ 


    if(($fh = fopen($filename, 'r')) !== false ) { 

       $headers = fread($fh, 0xA00); 
       $n1 = ( ord($headers[0x21C]) - 1 ); 
       $n2 = ( ( ord($headers[0x21D]) - 8 ) * 256 ); 
       $n3 = ( ( ord($headers[0x21E]) * 256 ) * 256 ); 
       $n4 = ( ( ( ord($headers[0x21F]) * 256 ) * 256 ) * 256 ); 
       $textLength = ($n1 + $n2 + $n3 + $n4); 
       if($extracted_plaintext = @fread($fh, $textLength)){ 

       }else{ 
            return docx2text($filename); // Save this contents to file 
       } 

        $text=str_replace(  chr(13) , "\n", $extracted_plaintext); 

        echo $text; 
    } 


} 

word('filename.doc');
```

E.X: filename.doc -> file contains statment "بسم الله الرحمن الرحيم"